# Features in Mobile Safari/Safari View Controller that are not available in WKWebView or UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview, mobile-safari, wkwebview, sfsafariviewcontroller

I'm trying to build a reliable engine on **iOS** to detect if a page is opened inside **Mobile Safari/Safari View Controller** (SFVC) or a **WebView** (WKWebView or UIWebView).

The main method I found is using the **User Agent**, which is not reliable, e.g. https://github.com/hgoebl/mobile-detect.js

Is there a list of features that are supported by Mobile Safari which are not supported by a WebView so I can use a library like Modernizr to detect where my page is opened?